# How to make an array cycle?

Tags: php, arrays

For example, I have array

```
// In
$arr = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5];
// Out
$cycled_arr = [5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0];
```

I did this:

```
$arr = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

// It cycles once
function array_start_push($array){
    return array_merge( array(array_pop($array)), $array);
}
// This function must cycle array $times times
function cycleArray($times,&$glArr){
    if (!isset($times)){
        $result = $glArr;
    } else {
        for ($loc = 0; $loc <= $times; $loc++) {    
        $result = array_start_push($glArr); 
        $glArr = $result;
    }   
    return $result;
}

$hmm = cycleArray($arr);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($hmm);
echo "</pre>";
```

Unfortunately it loading the page, be careful to execute!

**Update:**

```
// In array
$arr = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

// Circle array once 
function array_start_push($array){
    return array_merge( array(array_pop($array)), $array);
}
// Cycling $times times
function cycleArray($times,&$glArr){
        for ($loc = 0; $loc <= $times; $loc++) { 
            $result = array_start_push($glArr); 
            $glArr = $result;
        }   
    return $result;
}

$hmm = cycleArray(0,$arr);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($hmm);
echo "</pre>";
```

But this makes a cycle once, although there is a null!

Comment: Warning: Missing argument 2 for cycleArray(), Warning: array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array,Warning: array_merge()

Comment: The example looks more randomized than cycled...

Comment: I don't get your definintion of "cycling". Do you want to swap the first and last elements with each other? Because that's what your expected output looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function:

```
function cycleArray($times, $glArr){
  for($i = 0; $i < $times; $i++)
  {
    //$glArr[] = array_shift($glArr);
    array_unshift($glArr, array_pop($glArr));
  }
  return $glArr;
}
```

Comment: was 0, 1 , 2 , 3, 4 , 5, became array(6) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(4)
  [4]=>
  int(5)
  [5]=>
  int(0)
}, instead of 5, 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 0

Comment: Oh, yes. This cycles in reverse direction. Ill fix it.

Comment: it's if cycling cycleArray(1,$glArr)

Answer (score 0):

It probably gives you an error because `cycleArray($arr);` doesn't exist. it needs 2 parameters.

Check your errorlog.

Comment: [Mon Jun 18 11:17:30 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Script timed out before returning headers: php-cgi.exe

Comment: [Mon Jun 18 11:22:56 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given i

Comment: and [Mon Jun 18 11:23:41 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

Comment: anyway, review my function. wait a lit bit

Comment: You are calling a function that needs an array and you're not giving the array. please look at your log files, fix the obvious mistakes etc. I don't have the time to come back after every minor change you made to guide you, so please, just look at your code, and fix the obvious mistakes. hints: if you call a function with 2 parameters, you must supply 2 parameters.

Comment: I did update (watch), but it's makes a cycle once with zero in.

Comment: Don't add more exclamation points, but try to ask more clear questions. As said, I'm not going to guide you through every step. Make clear what you expect and why, make clear what actually happens, and ask a clear question. Furthermore, did you read that comment I posted about accepting answers?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually mean *cycle* and not whatever it is your example shows:

```
function cycle(array $arr, $steps) {
    return array_merge(array_slice($arr, $steps), array_slice($arr, 0, $steps));
}

var_dump(cycle(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 3));
```

results in:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=> int(4)
  [1]=> int(5)
  [2]=> int(1)
  [3]=> int(2)
  [4]=> int(3)
}
```

Comment: it's really useful too, cannt accept unfortunately already. Hope voting will help.

Comment: or Stop! Strange it. Test it again pls.

Comment: function cycle(array $arr_in, $steps) {
    return array_merge(array_slice($arr_in, $steps), array_slice($arr_in, 0, $steps));
}

var_dump(cycle(array(0,1,2,3,4,5), 1));
// resulted : array(6) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) [3]=> int(4) [4]=> int(5) [5]=> int(0) }

Comment: Well, `5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0` simply does not make any sense. What is the logic for that?!

Comment: logic in cycling, what if I want to turn over around an array five times?

Comment: How do you define "turn over"? When cycling an array, the numbers should still be in order. `5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0` is not in order. `4, 5, 1, 2, 3` is.

Comment: I dont need an order as it is, anyway, I already have a solution that works great, thank you deceze!

Comment: If you don't need them in order, just [`shuffle`](http://php.net/shuffle) the array.